# (Android Studio) How to set a specified value on an imageview?

Tags: java, android, imageview

Let's say I have an assets folder with a bunch of images for a deck of cards. I put the images from the assets folders into an arraylist of strings. I set my imageview file, cards, to change into a random image from the arraylist.

> cards.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(cardsList.get(random))));

If I want to set the Ace cards equal to the value 10, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: You can do this using `hashmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `hashmap`

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (String card : cardsList)
        {
            if(card.equals("Ace")) // or whatever string to be mapped to value 10
                map.put(10, card);
            if(card.equals("King"))
                map.put(9, card);

        }
```

Then `map.get(10)` will return "Ace" string

```
cards.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(map.get(random))));
```